# Starting tomcat server in eclipse shows the port numbers are already in use

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I installed tomcat8 om my windows and it runs successfully on browser, but when I configure tomcat in eclipse it shows the error that port numbers are already in use. This happens even when I change the port the number. It shows the same error message. I changed the port a lot of times, but I keep having the same problem.

What is the problem and how can I delete all tomcat related services on windows to restart my tomcat installation? Can any one guide me to fix the problem?

[image: this is the screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

Stop all java processes except for Eclipse, stop the Tomcat8 service if you have one. Then start Tomcat from under Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change all these ports and start again your Tomcat, just double click on your server and make your changes and save.

Answer (score 0):

The ports 2034, 8086, 2036 are assigned to some other services.
Your tomcat is also trying to listen on above port

You have two options here

1) Find out the services which are running on above ports and stop them(even if it is tomcat).
   [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-process-has-open-linux-port/) is step to find the service running on particular port

2) Configure your eclipse-tomcat to listen/ run on different ports.
   [Check it to run tomcat on different port](http://www.codejava.net/servers/tomcat/how-to-change-port-numbers-for-tomcat-in-eclipse)